# How to create an incoming connection in C#?

Tags: c#

It is possible to manually create an incoming connection, but how can we create an incoming connection in C#? Is there any API we can use?

Creating Modem Incoming connection, which we normally do by clicking Start Menu----> MyNetwork places----->Select View Network connection----> Create New connection ----->select setup advanced connection---->Click Next---->Select Accept incoming connection---Click next and select the modem.

RAS Client and RAS Server. Got information on RAS Client but no information on RAS Server.

Comment: you talking about .Net Remoting?

Comment: Unclear. What kind of "incoming connection" you need? Do you want to create server or client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) might help.

> Provides remote access service (RAS) components for .NET languages like C#, VB.NET, and C++ CLR projects (2.0.50727 and later only).